# Probability distribution for switches on a board

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a switch board as follows.

[image]

When you turn on the board, each switch has a 0.9 probability of working properly. When a switch is working properly, current can pass through it. I need to find the probability distribution for Y, the number of closed paths from a to b, when all switches are turned on.

So far I have determined there are 3 possible values for Y: 0, 1, or 2 open and working paths.

P(0) = (0.1)(0.1)(0.1) = none working

P(1) = (0.9)(0.9) + (0.9) = 1 and 2 working or 3 working

P(2) = (0.9)(0.9)(0.9) = all working

That's the work I've done so far. I know the probabilities have to all add up to 1, so I'm a little confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(0)$ should be $0.1 \cdot (1-0.9^2)$: you know #3 must fail, but you only need at least one of #1 and #2 to fail. You only considered if both #1 and #2 fail.

$P(1)$ should be $0.9^2 \cdot 0.1 + (1-0.9^2) \cdot 0.9$ because you want the probability that *exactly* one path is working. I think you found the probability for *at least* one path.

---

Edit: They do add up to $1$.
$$P(0)+P(1)+P(2) = 0.1 \cdot (1-0.9^2) + 0.9^2 \cdot 0.1 + (1-0.9^2) \cdot 0.9 + 0.9^3=1.$$

Comment: Aren't P(0), P(1), and P(2) supposed to add up to 1, though? Here they exceed 1.

Comment: @aCSE They do add up to $1$.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I added something where I should have multiplied. Thank you.